# LibGdx Gdx-Pay extension get item price

Tags: java, android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I use gdx-pay and works fine. But now I need to show the local pricing of item (fullversion) to the user before they click the buy button. I discovered that the `getInformation()` method is still implemented in android (`PurchaseManagerAndroidOpenIAB`).

I want to keep using gdx-pay; is there another way to get the local price (currency) and show it to the user?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old and openiab support is deprecated. Local pricing is available in getInformation() for googlebilling and googleplay implementations, so use them.